# AngularJS router is not kicking in when I enter the base url in browser address bar

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am serving an Angular app using Node.js at `http://localhost:8080/`. However, when I enter this URL in the browser address bar the home template does not show in the application content area - only the top nav shows (which is part of an outer shell). Here's my router configuration:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(configRouter);

configRouter.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

function configRouter($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
            controller: 'Home',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/profile', {
            templateUrl: 'profile/profile.html',
            controller: 'Profile',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}
```

The interesting part is that when I click the links in the top nav the correct templates are loaded (including the home template). Here's the code for my top nav:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/profile">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried various URL combinations in the browser address bar, but nothing works:

```
http://localhost:8080/
http://localhost:8080/#
http://localhost:8080/#/
```

What may be the issue? And how is it that the same URLs are working when invoked from within the app?

Thanks in advance for your time.

**Edit**

BTW I am following John Papa's AngularJS Style Guide example almost exactly. This may have something to do with my ng-view embedded in shell.html:

```
<div data-ng-controller="ShellController as vm">
    <div data-ng-include="'layout/topnav.html'"></div>

    <section id="content" class="content">
        <div data-ng-view class="shuffle-animation"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

But he has it exactly this way - see [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos/blob/master/modular/src/client/app/layout/shell.html#L16).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with the angular-router: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1213. The discussion suggests a workaround which is not pretty. As far as I can tell, angular-ui-router has the same issue - see some details here: https://github.com/johnpapa/generator-hottowel/issues/22. At the moment, the best solution is to avoid nesting ng-view using an ng-include.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I used `ng-view` in `main.html` and loaded it in `index.html` (which is the first file that gets loaded)
Then route (controller) didn't get activated from the url but when i clicked on links in my app it worked.

Then i moved the `ng-view` from `main.html` and placed directly in `index.html` then it worked from url also.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, if I move my ng-view to index.html, the view indeed gets rendered on load, however I loose my top nav :-(

Answer (score 0):

You may have to specify a base URL for all relative scripts on your page:

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.companyXYZ.com/scripts/" target="_blank">
```

More information about the base tag can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp).

Comment: Adding `<base href="http://localhost:8080/" target="_blank">` makes no difference.